# ComboBox select specific object id

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have a `ComboBox<Category>` which I can easily fill with my `ObservableList<Category>`.

I want in a initialization popup window to set that `ComboBox` value to a specific `Category.getName()`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Select](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html#select-T-) the required item in the [SelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html) of the [ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#getSelectionModel--).

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select("oranges");
```

Here is a sample app to demo this:

[image: combodemo]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboControl extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "apples",
                "oranges",
                "pears"
        );

        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select("oranges");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(comboBox)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Thx, i was thinking why it's not working for me, then i realized that i used another constructor without specific object parameter so why I had always null value... thx mate